# Error Updating lookup field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, master-detail

I have a use-case where I have to fetch all the meetings available. On selection of one meeting, I have to show the corresponding Attendees. Then I should give an option to display all unrelated attendees and map selected ones to the meeting. I have built my controller according.

But I am getting an error while mapping an attendee to the meeting. Attendee has a lookup field for Meeting. I have written comments accordingly. Please help

```
public class EventManagement{
    public string selected{get;set;}
    public List<Selectoption> options{get;set;}
    public string meets{get;set;}
    public List<Selectoption> opt{get;set;}
    public List<Meeting__c> meeting{get;set;}
    public boolean Test{get;set;}
    public boolean renderTable{get;set;}
    public boolean renderNew{get;set;}
    public boolean imp{get;set;}
    public List<AttendeesWrapper> attndWrap{get;set;}
    public List<AttendeesWrapper> attndWrap2{get;set;}
    public List<AttendeesWrapper> mapWrap{get;set;}
    public List<Attendee__c> attList{get;set;}
    public Meeting__c meetn {get;set;}
    public List<Attendee__c> attList1{get;set;}




    // Used to fetch list of meetings
    public EventManagement(){
        Test=true;
        opt=new List<Selectoption>();
        meeting=new List<Meeting__c>();
        meeting=[select ID,Name from Meeting__c];

        opt.add(new Selectoption('','----SELECT----'));   
        for(Meeting__c mee : meeting){ 
            opt.add(new selectoption(mee.ID,mee.Name));
          }
    }


    // Used to fetch list of attendees related to a meeting  
    public void myAttendees(){
       for(Meeting__c mt : meeting){
            if(mt.name==meets)
                meetn=mt;           
       }

        attList=new List<Attendee__c>();
        attList=[Select Id,Name,Attendee_Email__c,Country__c,Status__c from Attendee__c where  Meeting__c=:meets];

        // Creating a wrapper list for attendees   
        attndWrap = new List<AttendeesWrapper>();

        for(Attendee__c attnd : attList){
          attndWrap.add(new AttendeesWrapper(attnd));
         }

        //used for showing the data at VF page
         if(attndWrap.size()>0){
             renderTable = true;
        }    
    } 


    // Used to get attendeees not related to any meeting   
    public void importAttendee(){
        imp=true;
        List<Attendee__c> attList1 = new List<Attendee__c>();

        attList1=[select id,name,Mobile__c,Country__c,Attendee_Email__c, Attendee__c.Meeting__c from Attendee__c where Meeting__c=null];

        attndWrap2 = new List<AttendeesWrapper>();
            for(Attendee__c wa : attList1){
              attndWrap2.add(new AttendeesWrapper(wa));
            }
    }


    //Used to map the selected attendee to the meeting      
    public void mapAttendee(){
        List<Attendee__c> atnds = new List<Attendee__c>();

        for(AttendeesWrapper atL : attndWrap2){

            if(atL.selected1 == true){
            //I am getting an de-referencing null object exception next line
                Attendee__c atn4 = atL.attn1;
                    atn4.Meeting__c=meetn.id;
                    atnds.add(atn4);
            }
        }
        upsert atnds;
        myAttendees();
        renderNew=true;
    }


    /* Wrapper Class */
    //Used for adding a checkbox    
    public class AttendeesWrapper {
        public Attendee__c attn1 {get;set;}
        public boolean selected1{get;set;}

        public AttendeesWrapper(Attendee__c ab) {
            this.attn1=ab;
            this.selected1=false;
        }

    }   
}
```

VF page :

```
<apex:page controller="EventManagement" > 
 <apex:form >    
    <apex:pageBlock id="M1">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Name of Meetings" rendered="{!Test}">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:selectList value="{!meets}" size="1" multiselect="false">
        <apex:outputLabel >Name of Meetings</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!opt}"></apex:selectOptions>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myAttendees}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel1" layout="none" rendered="{!renderTable}">
       <table align="centre" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="20px" border="2px solid black" bgcolor="pink" id="t1" rendered="{!renderTable}" >
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Attendee Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

     <apex:repeat value="{!attndWrap}" var="mr"  >
         <tr>
             <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!mr.selected1}"/></td>   
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr.attn1.name}"></apex:inputField></td>
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr.attn1.Attendee_Email__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr.attn1.Country__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
              <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr.attn1.Status__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
         </tr>
     </apex:repeat> 
     </table>
     </apex:outputPanel>

     <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!renderTable}">
         <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updateAttendee}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!newAttendee}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Upsert" action="{!upsertAttendee}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteAttendee}"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Import" action="{!ImportAttendee}"/>
     </apex:pageBlock> 


     <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" layout="none" rendered="{!imp}">
       <table align="centre" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="20px" border="2px solid black" bgcolor="pink" id="t3" rendered="{!imp}" >
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Attendee Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

     <apex:repeat value="{!attndWrap2}" var="mr1"  >
         <tr>
             <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!mr1.selected1}"/></td>   
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr1.attn1.name}"></apex:inputField></td>
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr1.attn1.Attendee_Email__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
             <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr1.attn1.Country__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
              <td><apex:inputField value="{!mr1.attn1.Mobile__c}"></apex:inputField></td>
         </tr>
     </apex:repeat> 
     </table>
     </apex:outputPanel>


     <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!imp}">
         <apex:commandButton value="Map" action="{!mapAttendee}"/>
     </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Error**

> **Visualforce Error**
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression `'{!mapAttendee}'` in component `<apex:commandButton>` in page event_management: Class.EventManagement.mapAttendee: line 82, column 1

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the exact text of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created `inputField` to capture Attendee so you have to use Attendee__c.Id

Second thing, `inputField` works with SObject, it will not work with instance of wrapper class, so this line will not work with `inputField`

`<td><apex:inputField value="{!mr.attn1.name}"></apex:inputField></td>`

And there are lot of issues in the code the way you are structuring the logic and think about proper naming conversion.

Like in this line where `Meeting__c` should expect Ids where as you are passing List of Names as `String`:

```
 attList=[Select Id,Name,Attendee_Email__c,Country__c,Status__c from Attendee__c where  Meeting__c=:meets];
```